# Prevent a TFS task (work item) from being "Resolved"

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I'm running into an inconvenience - I have specific tasks in TFS that I want to be associated with multiple check-ins before they are resolved, but Visual Studio defaults the check-in association to "Resolve", requiring me (or whoever is doing the check-in), to change this to "Associate", before checking in. Is there a way to change this default, per user? Perhaps prevent the status ("Resolved") on specific tasks altogether?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Visual Studio:

Tools -> Options -> Source Control -> Visual Studio Team Foundation Server

Uncheck "Resolve associated work items on check-in".

Comment: Wow; can't believe I missed this - it's exactly what I was looking for.